# blu-ray archiving in vmware ESXi 4

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I need some advice about using blu-ray writer for archiving data on vmware ESXi 4. At office we have IBM System x3400 Tower server with ESXi 4 hipervisor and OpenSuse and CentOS GNU/Linux system as guests. Will blu-ray writer work in this setup, and if it will is there any particular model you can suggest.

Best regards

IBM System x3400 Tower server specification:

1x Intel Quad-Core Xeon E5410 2.33GHz/ 12MB/ 1333MHz (2x CPU max)
Intel 5000P chipset, 2x 1GB PC2-5300 DDR2 667MHz SDRAM ECC Chipkill (32GB max)
2x4GB (2x2GB) PC2-5300 CL5 ECC DDR2 FBDIMM (x3400, x3550, x3650)
SAS/SATA Hot-Swap Open Bay (0xHDD std, 4xHDD max, 8xHDD optional)
ServeRAID 8K dual channel SAS/SATA controller (RAID 0,1,1E,10,5,6, 256MB, Battery Backup)
Graphics ATI® RN50(ES1000) 16MB DDR, CD-RW/DVD Combo
no FDD
GigaEthernet, Tower with Power Supply 835W (opt Redudant)
Slot 1: half-length, PCI-Express x8(x4 electrical)
Slot 2: full, PCI-Express x8 
Slot 3: full, PCI-Express x8
Slot 4: full, 64-bit 133MHz 3.3v PCI-X
Slot 5: full, 64-bit 133MHz 3.3v PCI-X ,
Slot 6: half-length, 32-bit 33MHz 5.0v PCI
ports: 4x USB (Vers 2.0), 2x PS/2, parallel, 2x serial (9-pin), VGA, RJ-45 (ethernet ),   RJ-45 (sys mgm)
HDD 4 x TB 7200rpm / Serial ATA II 3.0Gb/s / 16MB, RoHS

Answer (score 2):

What software do you envisage backing this up with, ESXi can't do it on it's own and you don't say whether you have vCenter 4 running or whether you're licensed for VMWare Data Recovery. If you intend to backup via a VM and PCI pass-through then you're going to have be very specific with your choice of motherboard, drive controller and drive itself - have you looked into this? Are you storing you VMs locally or on a SAN/NAS?

Comment: I agree... Need more info to help answer the question